# Accordion Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi I have this accordion which was part of a wordpress theme and by default the accordion opens the first section. I have tried deleting and tweaking this code but i can't seem to get it to show no open sections.

```
//Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
$('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
//Set The Accordion Content Width
var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
$('.accordion-content').css({
    'width': contentwidth
});
//Open The First Accordion Section When Page Loads
$('.accordion-header').first().toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
$('.accordion-content').first().slideDown().toggleClass('open-content');
// The Accordion Effect
$('.accordion-header').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
        $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-     header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: It shows you right in the comments which lines of code are toggling the active class on the first section. Just remove those 2 lines.

Comment: thanks but i did and still opened it. I was hoping that it would be that easy.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a cache issue after making those changes?  If this is in a separate JS file, that could be your problem.

Comment: After making the changes, load the page in a private browsing window to rule out a cached Javascript file as @JonathanCarter suggested.